# How to sort a list of string?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of persons `List<person>`

```
public class Person
{
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

their age sorrily is in `string` but is infact of type `int` and has values like `"45", "70", "1" etc.`. How can I sort the list from older to younger?

calling `people.Sort(x => x.Age);` doesn't give the desired result. thanks.

Comment: What *is* the desired result?

Comment: as I said sorting from older to younger :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast each string to an int, then order them, largest to smallest:

```
var oldestToYoungest = persons.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.Age));
```

That should give you the desired result (assuming ages of "7", "22", and "105"):

```
105
22
7
```

If you sort them as strings, you won't get the desired result, as you found out. You'll end up with a list ordered alphabetically, like:

```
"7"
"22"
"105"
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work (assuming that `people` is a `List<Person>`) :

```
people = people.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Age)).ToList();
```

If you don't want to create a new `List`, alternatively you can implement `IComparable<T>` for your class:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public string Age { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return int.Parse(other.Age).CompareTo(int.Parse(this.Age));
    }
}
```

Then you just need to use `Sort` method:

```
people.Sort();
```